# Variable access issue in Fat Free Framework

Tags: php, variables, global-variables, fat-free-framework

My issue in accessing global variables in Fat Free Framework. Particularly, the only issue is in getting 'file_path' variable from code:

```
$f3->route('GET /d/@id',
function ($f3) {

    // Lots of DB code, where which in the end returns $file_id and $file_name

    $file = "upload/";
    $file .= $file_id . "/";

    $file .= $file_name;

    $f3->set('file_path', $file);

    $f3->set('content','download.htm');
    echo View::instance()->render('layout.htm')

}
);
```

Then I call /getfile from download.htm:

```
<a href="/getfile"> GET IT! </a>
```

And then I try to access the 'file_path' variable from another route, but nothing $f3->get('file_path') returns NULL:

```
$f3->route('GET /getfile',
function ($f3) {

    $file = $f3->get('file_path');

    var_dump($file);
}
);
```

Moreover, other global variables, accessed through $f3->get() work fine. For example

```
$f3->route('GET /getfile',
    function ($f3) {

    $db = $f3->get('DB');

    var_dump($db);
}
);
```

gets $db variable perfectly. Changing local and global variable names didn't help. Any ideas on what is happening? :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`file_path` is only accessable while you're on `/d/@id`. You have to cache the variable or save it in a SESSION. You're able to access `DB` because you set it outside of any route.

```
$f3->route('GET /d/@id',
function ($f3) {
    // Lots of DB code, where which in the end returns $file_id and $file_name

    $file = "upload/";
    $file .= $file_id . "/";

    $file .= $file_name;

    $f3->set('SESSION.file_path', $file);

    $f3->set('content','download.htm');
    echo View::instance()->render('layout.htm')
}
);


$f3->route('GET /getfile',
function ($f3) {

    $file = $f3->get('SESSION.file_path'); // you might clear the file_path then

    var_dump($file);
}
);
```

Comment: Oh wow, now it looks obvious, when you explained it. Anyways, the problem is solved. Many thanks!